# Nested generic return type

Tags: java, generics

How can I get rid of the questionmarks to make this method type safe?

```
private Map<String, ?> encapsulate(String rootName, List<?> data) {
    Map<String, List<?>> rootMap = new HashMap<String, List<?>>();
    rootMap.put(rootName, data);
    return rootMap;
}
```

Im passing a String and a List as parameters. I want the return type of that method to be:

```
 Map<String, List<type_the_list_had_before>>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you can make that method generic. For anything more, we need some more information. How are you invoking that method. Do you want it to return wildcard parameterized map?

Comment: Change it to `private <T> Map<String, List<T>> encapsulate(String rootName, List<T> data)`.

Comment: @mrjink: Please make it an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comment to answer:

Change it to

```
private <T> Map<String, List<T>> encapsulate(String rootName, List<T> data)
```